Enabling the double-tap gesture on Apple Watch
I am trying to add double tap support in my watch app but i am facing
"Cannot infer contextual base in reference to member 'primaryAction'"

My testing device is watch os 10.5 version
My testing device is watch seria 9
Min support version watch os 11

Also tried to create a new project and still the same error.
Does anyone have an idea what might be?
I am trying to add double tap support in my watch app but i am facing
"Cannot infer contextual base in reference to member 'primaryAction'"

My testing device is watch os 10.5 version
My testing device is watch seria 9
Min support version watch os 11

Also tried to create a new project and stil
